# Fetch a map of lists in Struts 2

Tags: java, list, jsp, struts2, ognl

I am creating a map

```
Map<String, List<String>> hm
```

I fetch the data from the db and set the values in the map.
Now I want to fetch these values in the JSP. I am able to iterate through the map. However I don't want to iterate through the list. Instead I want to access the elements of the list by index i.e. `'0'`,`'1'`, etc.
How can this be achieved?

```jsp
<s:iterator value="mapCred">                        
                        <tr>
                            <td>
<input type="radio" id="<s:property value='key' />" />
<inpyt type="text" value="mapCred['%{key}'].get(0)" />
</s:iterator>
```

or

```jsp
    <inpyt type="text" value="mapCred['%{key}'][0]" />
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```jsp
<s:textfield name="mapCred['%{key}']" value="%{value[0]}" />
```

Comment: I cannot use `s:textfield' since all the fields are of different type. eg text,radio.password etc

Comment: Then you should explore Struts tags library, it has tags that render the  input filed for each type.

Comment: ok using your hint i managed to do it using html tags and `<s:property value=" value[1]">`  Is there any specific reason to use struts2 tags only?

Comment: You can write html tags but OGNL is evaluated only in Struts tag's attributes and you missing some features that Struts 2 is for.

Comment: ok for eg I am trying to use struts2 radio tag but I dont want to display any values(label) along with that radio button. How can I achieve that?

Comment: This is a different question, you can ask it separately.